# Change a text on a woocommerce website using code

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the english text "By submitting this form, you hereby agree that we may collect, store and process your data that you provided" in the bottom of the page with something else in Arabic. I'm using Wordpress with Woocommerce plugin and divi theme builder.
this is the url of the page i'm trying to edit (https://blockchainarabi.com/checkout/)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods; using plugin and manually! Change a text on a woocommerce website using code is a manual method!

I'd suggest, use Google Fonts and text for your site. As there are numerous beautiful fonts that Google provides which improves user experience and helps you to boost user engagement.
Just follow the below-mentioned steps:
**Steps:**

Step 1: Find the fonts that you want to use on your website.

Step 2: Then, select the fonts by clicking on a plus sign (+) icon, You will see this in the top right section of every font family box.

Step 3: A Family Selected tab will appear on the bottom side, Just click it there and then click on customize and then, modify and select the different styles of fonts.

Step 4: Then, Go to Embed and copy the Standard field URL. You can see in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csuqj.png)

Step 5: Next, in the process is to add the following code into functions.php file via FTP client.

```
function wpblog_add_google_fonts() {
wp_enqueue_style( ' wpblog_google_fonts ', ' https://fonts.googleapis.com/css...', false );}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpblog_add_google_fonts' );
```

then save it.
See, it's that simple!

Note: Don’t forget to change the URL link with your own

Comment: Thanks Farhan for your comment. I’m trying to change the text not the font. There is a text written in English On the bottom of the page and I can’t find it in the code files. Any work arounds?